# DotnetCore service for auth

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, microservices

I am working on a bigger project, but the main idea and issue is that I want to create micro services, as follows.

1) I want to create an application that handles Login/Register (with JWT)

2) I have an open app that needs to be secured using the first app, as follows

You go to login.mock.com -> use your credentials, it will go to the first app and generate a JWT, if all ok, you get redirected to de second app (portal.mock.com)

On portal.mock.com you will be able to access the apis, based on your roles.

The main questions is, is it possible to do the authentication in a different application and then the one that requires authorization, in .NetCore 2.1?

If so, can you please point me to the right direction? I haven't found anything yet.

The idea is that since i have a big platform i want it to split in more smaller services and this is one of the issues

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you to first look at [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) and then on [IdentityServer](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/)

Comment: thanks, that's what i was looking for

Comment: Hey @Ofiris , please put this in the answer section , this is exactly the go forward approach :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The used approach was somehow the one suggested by @Ofiris in the comment but with some changes.

I created an identity application that owns the users and generates JWT with audience set based on the roles assigned to the user for different services. In order to authorize i include the roles in the JWT claims